# ways to segment a consecutive list

Tags: r

I would like to know if there is an additional way to segment a consecutive list with the below structure without using unlist and relist with an sheceleton or structure and also not using unlist and split with cut points.

```
D <- list(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4,5,6)) 
D
[[1]]
[1] 1,2,3,4
[[2]] 
[1] 1,2,3,4,5,6
[[3]]
[1] 1,2,3,4
[[4]]
[1] 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

into

```
[[1]]
[1] 1,2,3,4
[2] 1,2,3,4,5,6
[[2]]
[1] 1,2,3,4
[2] 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: Correct, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this would help

```
lapply(seq(1, length(D), by =2), function(i) D[i:(i+1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` takes and object and a factor and returns a list, `unsplit` reverses the operation:

```
> f <- c(1,1,2,2)
> (S <- split(D, f))
$`1`
$`1`[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

$`1`[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6


$`2`
$`2`[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

$`2`[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6


> unsplit(S, f)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: I get the idea could not find anything similar on the site although the example is different, thanks.